# How can one show that $f(0)=0$ for $f$ satisfying certain conditions?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Given the functional equation 
$$f(x+(1+x)f(y))=y+(1+y)f(x)$$

Such that $f:(-1,\infty) \to (-1,\infty)$ and the function $g(x):=\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is strictly increasing in $I=(-1,0)\cup(0,+\infty),$ how can one show that for every $t \in I$ we have 
$f(t)\neq t$?

Plugging $x=y=0,$ that makes $f(f(0))=f(0).$
Does that mean that $f(0)=0$?

Making $x=y,$ $f(x+(1+x)f(x))=x+(1+x)f(x)$ so we make $x+(1+x)f(x)=t$ that makes $f(t)=t$ but we can't make $t=0$ because $t$ is not in $I$? So do I have to use the fact that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is increasing?

Then after all this work we have to deduce that $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{-x}{x+1}$ for $x \in (-1,\infty).$

Comment: Do $F$ and $f$ denote the same function here?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 fixed

Comment: what is 'inters'?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I'm guessing intersection :)

Comment: Intersection @MichaelMedvinsky

Comment: To answer your question in line 5, $f(f(0)) = f(0)$ does not imply that $f(0) = 0$ unless you have other facts. For instance, $f(x) = 1$ satisfies $f(f(0)) = f(0)$  but not $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: ok, but what is the intersection of $[-1,0]$ and $[0,\infty]$ if not only $0$?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I writed before someone edited my question : $]x,y[$ in frensh countries that means $(x,y)$

Comment: it was me, and I'm not familiar with these notations, so I guess not only me.... but then you have empty set, perhaps you want union $\cup$?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky yes !! This is what im looking for "Union"

Comment: Try substituting $-1$ for $x$.

Comment: ^If the domain is $]-1,\infty[$ i.e. $(-1,\infty)$, then substituting $x = -1$ doesn't work.

Comment: @jimmyk4542 Right now, the domain is listed as $[-1,\infty)$.

Comment: Is $g$ increasing on $I$ or strictly increasing?

Comment: @user233658: I have adjusted things to try to make the formatting clearer and to match your original post's apparent intent. Please let me know if I have misinterpreted anything.

Comment: @CameronBuie It's fixed

Comment: @CameronBuie is it clear for you now ?

Comment: Looks better! Adam Black [brings up a good point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577587/how-can-one-show-that-f0-0-for-f-satisfying-certain-conditions?noredirect=1#comment3211369_1577587), though. By "$g(x)$ is increasing on $I,$" do you mean (1) "if $x,y\in I$ with $x<y,$ then $g(x)<g(y)$," or do you mean (2) "if $x,y\in I$ with $x<y,$ then $g(x)\le g(y)$"?

Comment: I mean't strictly increasing @CameronBuie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this will do the trick for showing that f(0) = 0:

Let's start by setting $x = 0$. We get

$$f(f(y)) = f(0) + (1+f(0))y.$$

By setting $y = 0$, we get

$$f(x) = f(x + (1+x)f(0)).$$

Apply now $f$ to expression above and use the first equation:

$$f(0) + (1+ f(0))x = f(0) + (1+f(0))(x + (1+x)f(0)).$$

This simplifies to

$$(1+x)(1+f(0))f(0) = 0$$
and thus $f(0) = 0$. We can also conclude that $f(f(y)) = y $, so f is its' own inverse.

---

Let suppose that there is numbers $a,b$ such that $a < b$ and $f(a) = b$ and $f(b) = a$ ($f$ is its' own inverse). Since function

$$ g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$$
is increasing by the hypothesis.  This means that $g(a) \le g(b)$, so

$$\frac{f(a)}{a} \le \frac{f(b)}{b} \iff  \frac{b}{a} \le \frac{a}{b} \iff$$
$$\frac{b^2 - a^2}{ab} \le 0 \iff \frac{(b-a)(b+a)}{ab} \le 0 \iff $$
$$ \frac{(b+a)}{ab} \le 0. $$

so we can say that there can't be such $a,b$ with same sign. So $x$ and $f(x)$ must have  different signs.

As OP noticed the equation 
$$ f(x+(1+x)f(x)) = x + (1+x)f(x) $$
holds. Let denote $x+ (1+x)f(x)$ as $t$. Then the equation says $f(t) = t$ but $f(t)$ and $t$ have different signs, therefore, $t$ must be zero. Thus, we conclude that $x + (1+x)f(x) = 0$ and the function $f$ is:

$$ f(x) = -\frac{x}{1+x}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I edited my question ! We should show that f(t)#t

Comment: By substituting $f(t) = t$ to the functional equation, we will see that functional equation holds. furthermore, g is increasing with $f(t) = t $ (but not strictly). So $f(t) = t$ fits the given conditions.

Comment: good point, I will fix that error